# How can I loop through all the characters that are 0 in a given string?

Tags: java, function, loops, type-conversion

I'm trying to remove trailing zeroes from an integer and here is my code so far.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class newuhu {
    public static int numTrailingZeros(int s) {
        BigInteger J = BigInteger.valueOf(s);
        String sb = J.toString();
        String Y = "";
        while (sb.length() > 0 && sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == '0') {
            sb.replaceAll("0"," ");


        }
        return Integer.parseInt(Y);
    }
```

Note: I turned my int into a Biginteger because I've been warned that some inputs may look like 20!, which is 2.432902e+18

However, my IntelliJ debugging tool tells me that variable sb isn't in the loop. So, I'm trying to understand what must be done to make sure `sb` is in the loop.

Please understand that I'm a beginner in Java so, I'm trying to learn something new.

Comment: `replaceAll` returns a **new** string, but you're throwing that result away. Maybe you meant `sb = sb.replaceAll("0"," ");`, though that would be far from efficient, and wrong as it would also replace other `0`s in the string, and there is need need for a loop.

Comment: Your conversion from `int` to `BigInteger` to `String` doesn't make much sense to me. What are you really trying to do here? You seem to have an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). And you never assign anything other than an empty string to `Y`, so `Integer.parseInt` will always fail. As an aside, in commonly accepted Java coding conventions, you local variables do not start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `sb.replaceAll("0","")` won't do anything.  You're throwing away the return value that contains your replaced string.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

What you probably want is something like this:

```
while (sb.length() > 0 && sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == '0') {
    sb = sb.replaceAll("0"," ");
```

I'm not sure you need a `while` loop, though.  ReplaceAll will... replace *all* of the zeros with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll replaces all occurrences of string with character that you want (ie space) so you don't need loop at all, also you're concerned about overflow so you should actually use BigInteger as a parameter, not int (int wont fit anything close to 20!) but there's another issue with your code, you said you want to replace trailing zeros but right now you will replace every 0 with blank character, you should try to use something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

```
public class newuhu {
public static int numTrailingZeros(BigInteger s) {
    String sb = s.toString();
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.replaceAll("0", "")); // consider returning something else if you're working with BigInteger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when doing [BigInteger.valueOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)) does not have an effect as a number to big for int will never be stored in an int. Also 20! is fine for int.

```
public static String trimTrailingZeros(String source) {
    for (int i = source.length() - 1; i > 0; ++i) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        if (c != '0') {
            return source.substring(0, i + 1);
        }
    }
    return ""; // or return "0";
}
```

Or if you prever BigInteger.

```
public static BigInteger trimTrailingZeros(BigInteger num) {
    while (num.remainder(BigInteger.TEN).signum() == 0) {
        num = num.divide(BigInteger.TEN); 
    }
    return num;
}
```

This should be fast as you only create one string (via [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))).

Comment: Your code removes leading `0`s, not trailing `0`s.

Comment: Oh you are right

Comment: I correced it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

(First: variables and fields should start with a small letter - when no constants.)

It should be

```
sb = sb.replaceAll(...)
```

as `sb` is not changed by `replaceAll`, only the replaced value is returned. The class String gives *immutable* values, that always remain the same, so you can assign a variable to a variable and changing values of either variable will never influence the other - no further sharing.

Then it should be:

```
sb = sb.replaceFirst("0$", "");
```

`replaceAll` would replace every 0, like "23043500" to "23435".

`replaceFirst` replaces the _regular expression: char '0' at the end `$`.

Overflow on the input number is not possible, as you are already passing an `int`.

```
public static int numTrailingZeros(int n) {
    while (n != 0 && n % 10 == 0) {
        n /= 10;
    }
    return n;
}

public static int numTrailingZeros(String n) {
    n = n.replaceAll("0+", "");
    if (n.isEmpty() || n.equals("-")) { // "-0" for pessimists?
       n = "0";
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(n);
}
```

`%` is the modulo operator, the remainder of an integer division 147 % 10 == 7.

The name is misleading, or you are calculating something different.

```
public static int numTrailingZeros(int n) {
    int trailingZeros = 0;
    while (n != 0 && n % 10 == 0) {
        n /= 10;
        ++trailingZeros ;
    }
    return trailingZeros ;
}
```